# jQuery toggle show XHTML Smarty some clahes maybe? It doesn't show

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml, smarty

at this page [new customer](http://www.euroworker.no/user/checkout/), there is some clash between the two scripts. I have been asked to make the content shown when clicking the "ny kunde" button.

*This script works fine now, thanks to Voyta.*

There is another script made by another person that finds Company CEO information and inputs the data into the fields.

When I put the show script into the page, this function sottped working, as did the show hide on the checkbox lower down in the page.

How can I find out what's clashing?
What am I looking for?
Should I just give up?

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/qGYVr/1/) of the code I got working (I'm a jQuery noob).

Code on my .tpl

```
  <button id="button1">&nbsp;</button>

    {literal}

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#button1").click(function() {
      $(".newCustomer").toggle("slow");
    });
});​
</script>

<div class="newCustomer">...
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you reformulate the question? I do not understand what your pint is. For what i can tell you should install FireBug in Firefox and check the console.log a lot of errors are thrown. On top of that you can insert jquery lint in your file header. It will show you what exactly, is wrong in your jquery syntax: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/

Comment: The point is that it doesn't work, that there are two or more scripts running on this page, I am totallynew to jQuery and I don't know how or what to look for.

Comment: Open your JavaScript console (and maybe install Firebug). You've got loads of JavaScript errors. Start on the first one (the missing `{` in the function literal as pointed out by Voyta) and work from there. Also you appear to be using both Prototype and jQuery. No good will come of this. Settle on a single framework.

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that. Since my boss added this other function into the page without telling me anything about it. Is there a way to do this show/hide thing with Prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error `click(function()1`

It should be:

```
$(function() {
    $("#button1").click(function() {
      $(".newCustomer").toggle("slow");
    });
});​
```

Comment: is there a `toggle('show')` ? i think it has to be `toggle('slow')`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that And seems to be working! But the org number getter isn't working now..

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier : since you are already using jQuery, you might as well use jQuery UI's nice dialog widget. It includes all the small things that are difficult to think of beforehand when you implement the whole thing by yourself :

- make the dialog modal in order to prevent interactions with the rest of the page while the dialog is open
- movable and resizable
- the "plugs" (callback functions) to define what to do when user clicks OK, cancel, or just closes the dialog...

See : http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form - try the modal form example

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this in the future, but for now I don't want to have to use a whole new thing when all I need is these two functions to work on the same page.